# woocommerce_subscription_status_updated hook is not called

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I put this in functions.php as last line.
I tested that error_log writes into a log.
trigger message never appears in the log..
It seems that custom_subscription_status_updated function is never called. I created new subscription , then i cancelled... no effect. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'custom_subscription_status_updated', 10, 3 );

function custom_subscription_status_updated( $subscription_id, $new_status, $old_status ) {
  //  error_log('trigger '.$subscription_id.' '.$new_status);
    error_log('trigger ');
    $filename =__DIR__.'/../../../test_file.txt';
    $file_content = 'trigger ';
    file_put_contents($filename, $file_content);
}
```

I found that    error_log('updated');
do_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', $this, $status_transition['to'], $status_transition['from'] );
This line in class-wc-subscription.php is not called...
no sure why...

but this is called..
add_action( 'wps_sfw_order_status_changed', 'order_status_changed', 10, 3 );

Comment: Okay, try this: find in the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin the hook is called, and temporarily add an `error_log()` there, and see if an entry is added. If there's not, then that explains why your callback isn't firing.

Comment: and where is that?

Comment: You'll need to search your codebase for the hook. WooCommerce Subscriptions is a premium plugin, so access to the codebase is limited to those that have paid for it.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the priority parameter. 10 to 1.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'custom_subscription_status_updated', 1, 3 );

function custom_subscription_status_updated( $subscription_id, $new_status, $old_status ) {
  //  error_log('trigger '.$subscription_id.' '.$new_status);
    error_log('trigger ');
    $filename =__DIR__.'/../../../test_file.txt';
    $file_content = 'trigger ';
    file_put_contents($filename, $file_content);
}
```

Comment: it does not help.